# How to handle ' in expected text while testing AngularJS application using Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to validate text on angularjs site, which has a single quote in between, trying below to handle it but getting an error.

```
it('Validation', function() {
    browser.driver.sleep(5000);
    var var1 = element(by.css('CSSPathHere'));
    browser.driver.sleep(10000);
    expect(var1.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(var1.getText()).toEqual('Textwith ' in between');
});
```

With above I am getting following error:

```
protractor conf.js
Using ChromeDriver directly...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Error: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have *unbalanced single quotes*, fix it:

```
expect(var1.getText()).toEqual("Textwith ' in between");
```

Note that you should've spotted the problem earlier - modern IDEs highlight syntax errors like this on the fly while you edit which saves a lot of time. Here is how it looks in `WebStorm`:

[image]

Comment: Great help, double quoting the text did work for me. Also thanks for recommending Webstorm, heard good things from few others as well, will look into it.